# WebView with an IFRAME android

Tags: android, iframe, webview, load

I want to load an HTML `<IFRAME>` inside an `WebView`, but I don't know why, it is not able to do so.

I am using following code to load `<IFRAME>`

```
webView.loadData("<iframe src=\"http://www.google.com\"></iframe>", "text/html",
                "utf-8");
```

Here's what I have tried.

```
WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
webViewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webViewSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

I have mentioned the internet permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have also tried settings the `WebViewClient` with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` always returning false.

But it just isn't working.

I have tried this with diffrent sites, i.e. sites other than, google.com.

I am testing this on, Samsung Nexus S running ICS 4.0.3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how it worked out.

I noticed Log cat was throwing me

> WebKit permission issue: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is
>   not supported before the WebViewCore is set up

To fix this, I had to add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in `<application>` tag of Manifest.

I was experiencing this on ICS and its found that the same issue will occur post Honeycomb devices.

Hope this will help some one out.

Comment: hi, what this android:hardwareAccelerated="true" means?

Comment: @Shardul: see screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/OyCxlwh.png  , hardwareAccelerated=true is set but iframe is unable to load google.com page

Comment: hi this android:hardwareAccelerated="true" property is not find in application tag

Comment: this defaults to true if minSDK or targetSDK >= 14, so doesn't solve for me

Answer (score 13):

Try with the below code:

```
webView.setInitialScale(1);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

Log.e(SimpleBillsConstants.SIMPLE_BILLS, width + "-" + height);

String data_html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head> <meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"target-densitydpi=high-dpi\" /> <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"> <link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5)\" href=\"hdpi.css\" /></head> <body style=\"background:black;margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;\"> <iframe style=\"background:black;\" width=' "+width+"' height='"+height+"' src=\""+VIDEO_URL+"\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe> </body> </html> ";

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://vimeo.com", data_html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Just a question. If you do `setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);` and after you also do `setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);` the latter will override the former right? Or you set one or the other and not both.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.PluginState

This will help your question I think. But as you said we can use any one.

Comment: I think this answer should be marked as correct answer because it worked perfectly well on my end

Answer (score 2):

following hack worked for me for loading iframes in webview.Hope some one still might find it useful

```
    String webContent="your data to be loaded in webview"
if(webContent.contains("iframe")){
                Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("src=\"([^\"]+)\"").matcher(webContent);
                matcher.find();
                String src = matcher.group(1);
                webContent=src;

                try {
                    URL myURL = new URL(src);
                    webView.loadUrl(src);

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {

                webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<style>img{display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 100%;}</style>" + webContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);}

        }
    }
```

Comment: What goes into webContent?